# Wrong value coming from the jsonobject - java

Tags: java, hashtable

This is the continuation of my last question:
[how to keep data stored into a hashtable - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233102/how-to-keep-data-stored-into-a-hashtable-java/15233343#15233343)

Here is the json:

```
{"DeviceID":"35181805087546548","TotalCount":"0","Timestamp":"2013-03-05 14:30:15"}
```

Here is the declaration of my hashtable:

```
    private static Hashtable<Integer,String> table = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger() ;
```

Here is code to parse the jsonobject:

```
        JSONObject jsonObj;
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(string);
            int id = jsonObj.optInt("DeviceID", count.addAndGet(1) );
            String name = jsonObj.toString();
            table.put(id, name);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Using the code below my id is always "2147483647" even if the "DeviceID" in the json changes. 
Any hint?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your value is too large for an int.  The largest allowable value is 2,147,483,647.  See [What is the maximum value for an int32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32).  You will need to parse the value as a long.

Comment: Sotirios, made the answer a statement rather that a question

Comment: +1 Looked like a valid answer before, so does it now. No need to be rude.

Answer (score 1):

The [maximum value of an integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java is 2,147,483,647, so your device ID doesn't fit. You will probably need to store it as a `long` (maximum value 9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

Answer (score 1):

The number you are getting is the maximum value of a signed integer, you need to use long, or your result is limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE.